# DIY Bootloader isn't doing what it should do

Tags: assembly, x86, qemu, bootloader, low-level

A while ago I wrote a bootloader with the help of a tutorial. But it was so complicated that I barely understood anything. So today I set out to make my own bootloader using my knowledge and Google. Nothing big, just a bootloader that activates what I could find and program and then passes the power on to the kernel.

My goal was to play with the video buffer a bit, so I activated it at the very beginning. Then I was told that I should switch to protected mode before I pass on the power to the kernel and that's where the problems started because I don't know exactly how to do it. For debug reasons I made 2 labels that simply paint dots on the screen, but sometimes I only had one and in the current state I only have a black screen.

My current code:

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

start:
    cli

    ; Initialize stack
    mov ax, 0x8000
    mov ss, ax
    xor sp, sp

    ; Initialize data segments
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    ; Switch to Video Mode
    mov ax, 0x0013
    int 0x10   

    call debug 

    
    lgdt [gdtr]
    
    jmp 0x08:skip 

[bits 32]
skip:

    mov eax, cr0
    or al, 1
    mov cr0, eax    

    mov ax, 0x10 
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax 
    jmp 0x08:0x1000 

debug:
    mov ax, 0xA000
    mov es, ax
    mov di, 320*100 + 100
    mov al, 0x0F
    stosb

debug2:
    mov ax, 0xA000
    mov es, ax
    mov di, 320*100 + 300
    mov al, 0x0F
    stosb


section .gdtr
gdtr:
    dw 0x17FF
gdt:
    dd 0x00000000, 0x00000000
    dd 0x00FFFFFF, 0x00CF9A00

; Boot signature
times 422-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

The floppy is loaded successfully.

Here to perhaps discover other mistakes of mine:
linker.ld in the kernel folder:

```
ENTRY(kernel_main)
SECTIONS {
    . = 0x1000;

    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }
    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }
    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
    }
}
```

entry.asm in the kernel folder:

```
section .text
global _start
extern kernel_main

_start:
    ; Initialize stack
    mov esp, mainFnStack + 4096 ; Point to the top of the stack space

    ; Draw dot for debugging
    mov ax, 0xA000
    mov es, ax
    mov di, 320*100 + 200
    mov al, 0x0F
    stosb

    ; Call main kernel function
    call kernel_main

    ; Infinite loop to halt execution
    jmp $

section .bss
mainFnStack resb 4096  ; Allocate 4096 bytes for the stack
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Im working with QEMU but I wasn't able to get GDB in combination with QEMU working.

---

Edit:

Here is the Makefile for the bootloader:

```
ASMC = nasm
FLAGS = -f bin -O3
SRC = boot.asm
DEST = ../../bin/boot.bin

all: $(DEST)

$(DEST): $(SRC)
    $(ASMC) $(FLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(DEST)
```

Makefile for the Kernel:

```
CC = gcc
LD = ld
ASMC = nasm
CFLAGS = -ffreestanding -c
ASMFLAGS = -f elf64
LDFLAGS = -o ../../bin/kernel.bin -T linker.ld
SRC_C = $(wildcard *.c */*.c)
SRC_ASM = $(wildcard *.asm */*.asm)
OBJ_C = $(patsubst %.c, obj/%.o, $(SRC_C))
OBJ_ASM = $(patsubst %.asm, obj/%.o, $(SRC_ASM))

all: ../../bin/kernel.bin

../../bin/kernel.bin: $(OBJ_C) $(OBJ_ASM)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ_ASM) $(OBJ_C)

obj/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

obj/%.o: %.asm
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(ASMC) $(ASMFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf obj ../../bin/kernel.bin
```

Makefile in the Project root:

```
all:
    $(MAKE) -C src/kernel
    $(MAKE) -C src/bootloader
    dd if=/dev/zero of=bin/floppy.img bs=1k count=1440 
    dd if=bin/boot.bin of=bin/floppy.img conv=notrunc seek=0
    dd if=bin/kernel.bin of=bin/floppy.img bs=512 seek=1 conv=notrunc



clean:
    $(MAKE) -C src/kernel clean
    $(MAKE) -C src/bootloader clean
    rm -f bin/floppy.img
```

If I pad to 510 I result in a binary that is around 550 Bytes big more or less

Comment: Please also show the commands that you use to build and run your program. At a glance, you aren't returning from the function `debug`, you are never loading let alone relocating any other parts of your kernel in the loader, your GDT contains only one descriptor, and the `times` directive before the 0AA55h signature should pad to 510 bytes not 422.

Comment: Your `call debug` happens while in Real Mode and it jumps to a 32-bit function. The very first instruction after this label, `mov ax, 0xA000`, will be translated as `mov eax, 0xC08EA000`, followed by `mov edi, 0x0FB07D64` and finally `stosb`. I'm not really sure why this doesn't triple-fault...but it definitely creates chaos.

Comment: @ecm I edited my question and added the Makefiles I use

Comment: @DarkAtom You're right that `debug` is assembled as 32-bit code but will be executed in 16-bit mode. Why should any of these instructions fault though? The `stosb` will run as `a16 stosb` so it cannot fault, it will only use `di` (low word of `edi`). Greater problem is it will run into `debug2` then into `gdtr` and crash. "If I pad to 510 I result in a binary that is around 550 Bytes big more or less" -- It may work with the `times` directive filling to 422 Bytes but only because you used a `section` directive. There is no reason to put the GDT into a section of its own.

Comment: @ecm removing the section helped now I have the 512 Bytes binary. But i don't really know how I'm meant to fix the crash

Comment: @ecm "Why should any of these instructions fault though?" I didn't mean to say that any of those specific instructions will fault, but from what I understand, OP is not getting a triple fault at all, just a black screen. I would assume that such chaos HAS to fault at some point...how (un)lucky does it have to be to run into an infinite loop? Most likely it throws `#UD`, which we don't know what the BIOS does with.

Comment: @DarkAtom Actually most possible byte values will decode as random valid instructions, you need more luck to actually hit an Undefined Operation or other fault. When my 86-DOS programs crash that often results in an apparent hang, even when my debugger has installed int 0, int 1, int 3, int 6, int 0Ch, and int 0Dh handlers.

Comment: @ecm That's a fair point, but `FF FF` is not a valid opcode. The problem with the code is that it never gets to execute the `FF FF` in the GDT's limit field. The `FF 17` is `call near [bx]` which goes to God knows where (unless `bx` is 0xFFFF), from where it probably never recovers and executes random opcodes as you say. Had it not been for this mistake (because the GDT certainly shouldn't be `0x1800` bytes long) it most likely would have triggered `int 6`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your program which switches to protected mode:

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

start:
    cli

    ; Initialize stack
    mov ax, 0x8000
    mov ss, ax
    xor sp, sp

    ; Initialize data segments
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    ; Switch to Video Mode
    mov ax, 0x0013
    int 0x10   

    ;; call debug ;; not needed
    
    lgdt [gdtr]
    
    ;; jmp 0x08:skip ;; not this early

    mov ax, 0x2401 ; enable A20 (might already be done but who knows)
    int 0x15

    cli ; I noticed that some virtual machines set FLAGS.IF after that BIOS call

    mov eax, cr0
    or al, 1
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp 0x8:skip

[bits 32]
skip:
    mov ax, 0x10 
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax 
    jmp 0x08:0x1000 ; I assume you want your code to continue here, but if this code is the only one loaded, it will jump to nothing (a.k.a. junk bytes)

debug: ; these are designed to run in Protected Mode
    mov byte [0xA0000 + 32100], 0x0F
    ret

debug2:
    mov byte [0xA0000 + 32300], 0x0F
    ret

gdtr:
    dw 23
    dd gdt
gdt:
    dd 0x00000000, 0x00000000
    dd 0x0000FFFF, 0x00CF9A00 ; code segment 0x08
    dd 0x0000FFFF, 0x00CF9200 ; data segment 0x10

; Boot signature
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

However, I should mention that you won't get very far if you switch to Protected Mode this early, since you are limited by the 512 bytes of the boot sector. Until you load a driver capable of talking to the hard drive directly, you will have to use `int 0x13` whether you like it or not (and, as it is a BIOS call, it is only available in Real Mode). There are also other things which need to be done while in Real Mode, such as getting the memory map using `int 0x15, eax=0xE820` but this is just a starting point.

Comment: Did this work for you? It looks like that it crashes and QEMU trys to restart it. But thanks I try to get it running

Comment: Of course it crashes. It jumps to `0x8:0x1000`, which doesn't contain anything. As I said at the end, you will have to load more stuff from the hard drive from Real Mode.

Comment: I missed this one. 

Would this be this block or does it need more that just that?

```asm
; Read Kernel from the disk
    mov ah, 0x02  ; read sectors from drive function
    mov al, 0x01  ; number of sectors to read
    mov ch, 0x00  ; cylinder number
    mov cl, 0x02  ; sector number, start from the second sector
    mov dh, 0x00  ; head number
    mov dl, 0x80  ; drive number, 0x80 for the first disk
    mov bx, 0x1000 ; destination address in memory
    mov es, bx
    xor bx, bx ; offset 0
    int 0x13
```

it looks bad I don't know how to do it

Comment: Don't copy paste blocks of code. Try to understand them. Yes, you want to use `int 0x13, ah=2` to load stuff from the hard drive. But you need to calculate the CHS address of the sector you want to read (and for that, you need to know where is your file on the drive). Also, `dl=0x80` specifies a hard disk drive, but in the question you mention you are using a floppy, which requires `dl=0`. [Here](https://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_in_x86_RealMode_(BIOS))'s a good resource.

Comment: I'm trying my best to understand it. Yes, I use Floppy and I just saw and changed this. But I don't know how to "calculate the CHS address of the sector".

Comment: It's just a trivial calculation, I linked a guide in my comment above, which, among other things, shows LBA to CHS conversion. LBA is just the address of the sector (starting from 0). How you acquire it depends a lot on how you format your floppy disk. If the rest of your bootloader is a file on the floppy, you will have to write a tiny FAT12 parser in the 512 bytes you are given. Or you can place it inside the "reserved" sectors of the filesystem where it's easier to access (but you will have difficulty formatting the floppy image that way).